# Button with Immediate="true" clears currently displayed validation messages

Tags: jsf-2

I have a commandButton that redisplays the page with help on a field.
This needs to work without JavaScript.
I don't want to trigger validation so I add immediate = true.
This works fine, however, any validation messages that were on the page disappear, whereas I want them to stay there.

```
<h:commandButton rendered="#{cc.attrs.helpId!= null}" styleClass="helpButton" value="?" type="submit" action="#{visibleHelp.toggle(cc.clientId)}" immediate="true" />

...

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{visibleHelp[cc.clientId] != null}" id="#{cc.attrs.name}_helpText" styleClass="help-text">
    <h:outputText value="#{help[cc.attrs.helpId]}"/>
</h:panelGroup>

...
```

Is this just how it is, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior. The faces messages are request scoped. Submitting a form creates a new request. With `immediate="true"` the input components not having that attribute won't be validated and hence not generate faces messages. On a synchronous (non-ajax) postback, the initial messages "disappear" because of a full page reload.

Just submit by ajax instead so that the page won't be fully reloaded.

```
<h:panelGroup id="helpButton">
    <h:commandButton rendered="#{cc.attrs.helpId!= null}" styleClass="helpButton" 
        value="?" action="#{visibleHelp.toggle(cc.clientId)}" immediate="true">
        <f:ajax render="helpButton helpSection" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>

...

<h:panelGroup id="helpSection">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{visibleHelp[cc.clientId] != null}" 
        id="#{cc.attrs.name}_helpText" styleClass="help-text">
        <h:outputText value="#{help[cc.attrs.helpId]}"/>
   </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

True, this involves under the covers still JavaScript, but there's no other feasible solution, or you must remove `immediate="true"` so that validation is re-executed for those input components.

Comment: Thanks, I had done the ajax bit, but our customer is into Progressive Enhancement, so I need a no script option too.

Comment: I think that the customer will have to live with it, most users have javascript. Your assertion that there is 'no other feasable solution' helps my position - Thanks again.